# Not receiving messages from XMPP server even device is connected to XMPP

Tags: android, xmpp

I am trying to setup `XMPP` server for mobile application.
On `XMPP` server my mobile device is connected ,but when I try to send notification I am not receiving it on device. 
I am receiving ping from server that mean there is connection between device and `XMPP`.

Below is my Tomcat log report:

```
18:45:35,327  INFO EjabberdXmppManager:207 - connected but not authenticated, so going to login...test1 18:45:35,328  INFO EjabberdXmppManager:247 - XMPPException while login - SASL authentication PLAIN failed: text

18:45:35,483  INFO EjabberdXmppManager:107 - connectionClosedOnError()
- stream:error (not-authorized) 18:45:36,483  INFO EjabberdXmppManager:121 - reconnectingIn() in secs – 9
```

And in Ejabberd log I am getting below warning:

```
2019-01-03 15:12:06.223 [warning] <0.545.0>@ejabberd_c2s:handle_auth_failure:447 (tcp|<0.545.0>) Failed c2s PLAIN authentication for test1@vspdragonap1 from ::ffff:IP: Invalid username or password
```

I have spent lot of time to resolve this issue but no luck.

Please help if anyone has faced same issue.

Comment: share your code which done for create connection and login

Answer (score 0):

According to the logs you provided - you simply did not authorize(login) properly. Username or password is wrong. Hence you do not have any active user session at XMPP server. That’s why you do not receive anything. 
You need to check your username and password.

Comment: Thank you, I am checking for user credentials. But why is it saying 'XMPPException while login - SASL authentication PLAIN failed: text'? is it due to wrong credentials or any other reason?

Comment: Wrong credentials

Comment: Yup, you were right,there was issue with credentails.I registered my user on ejabberd and now it's working fine. Thank you.